# ¿En qué estoy fallando con estas líneas de code

Tags: php, html, mysqli

estoy tratando de subir archivos a través de un form y un input type=file, pero al ejecutar el código me aparecen los siguientes errores:

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
          ̃,                    .

Aquí os dejo el code html + php:

```
<form class="postulacion" method="POST" action="assets/php/send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form_cv">
                <label for="cv">
                    Suba su curriculum
                </label>
                <input type="file" name="cv" value="Adjuntar" title="Adjunte un archivo." size="150" maxlength="150" required />
            </div>
```

PHP:

```
include 'data.php'; //file which contains db config.
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'])) { 
     
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$movil = $_POST['movil'];
$puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
$seleccion = $_POST['seleccion'];   // En los casos de radio inputs, tenemos que asignarle un mismo "name" a los dos, para que funcione de forma correcta. 
                              // Quedaría algo así: Seleccion = no, o Seleccion = si.


$query = "INSERT INTO loco12(email, nombre, apellido, movil, puesto,  seleccion) VALUES('$email','$nombre','$seleccion','$movil','$puesto','$apellido')";




     
      // creamos las variables para subir a la db
        $ruta = "../../data-gathered/files"; 
        $nombrefinal= trim ($_FILES['cv']['name']); //Eliminamos los espacios en blanco
        $nombrefinal= preg_replace (" ", "", $nombrefinal);//Sustituye una expresión regular
        $upload= $ruta . $nombrefinal;  



        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $upload)) { //movemos el archivo a su ubicacion 
                    
                    echo <<<EOT
                    
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/completed.css">
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./assets/img/favicon.ico">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=./success/index.php">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                   <div class="root">
                   </div>
                   </body>
                   </html>

                   
                    
          EOT;         
                   
                    
                    }
}
}
 else {
    print 'xd';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la líne 27 utilizas [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) que está esperando como primer parámetro una expresión regular, sin embargo en el primer parámetro estás pasando "", por eso te da ese error.

Parece que lo que quieres hacer es quitar los espacios, puedes hacerlo con [str_replace](http://ttps://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

```
$nombrefinal= str_replace(" ", "", $nombrefinal);
```

El segundo, veo que te falta una barra para separar la ruta del nombre del archivo, no la he visto en el resto del código.

```
 $upload= $ruta . '/' . $nombrefinal;
```